# Problems Migrating from Jasmine 1.3 to 2.0 Problems with done and SetTimeOut

Tags: jasmine

I recently started migrating from jasmine 1.3 to 2.0 and ran into some problems.

This is how my old test looked like:

```
it("should start heartbeat after successful login and stop heartbeat after logout", function () {
    runs(function () {
        auth.hbTimeout = 500;
        var loggedIn = auth.login("USERWITHSESSION", "xyz", {});
        expect(loggedIn).toBe(true);
        expect(auth.getAuthenticated()).toBe(true);
        expect(auth.user).toBeDefined();
        expect(auth.user.Session).toEqual(74790750);
        setTimeout(function () {
            auth.stopHeartbeat();
            auth.user.Session = 74790760;
        }, 2000);
    });
    waitsFor(function () {
        return auth.user.Session == 74790760;
    }, "The session-id should have been changed", 2600);
    runs(function () {
        auth.heartbeat();
        expect(auth.getAuthenticated()).toBe(false);
        expect(auth.user).not.toBeDefined();
        auth.login("USERWITHSESSION", "xyz", {});
        setTimeout(function () {
            auth.user.Session = 74790750;
        }, 500);
    });
    waitsFor(function () {
        return auth.user.Session == 74790750;
    }, "The session-id should have been changed back", 1100);
    runs(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            auth.logout();
        }, 2000);
    });
    waitsFor(function () {
        return auth.getAuthenticated() == false;
    });
    expect(auth.user).not.toBeDefined();
});
```

I want to replicate the part up until the first waitsFor(). for the two second timeout I tried a setTimout() and moved the expect into an afterEach.

As far as I understand it, jasmine should wait two seconds an then execute the code, still the expect is always wrong and the test fails.

This is how I did it:

```
 describe("this is a async nested describe",function(){

    afterEach(function(done){
        expect(auth.user.Session).toBe(74790760);
    });

    it("let's do this",function(){

       auth.hbTimeout = 500;
        var loggedIn = auth.login("USERWITHSESSION", "xyz", {});
        expect(loggedIn).toBe(true);
        expect(auth.getAuthenticated()).toBe(true);
        expect(auth.user).toBeDefined();
        expect(auth.user.Session).toEqual(74790750);


        setTimeout(function() {
            auth.stopHeartbeat();
            auth.user.Session = 74790760;
            done();
        },2000);
    });

});
```

Can someone give me a hint? Whatever I do, even if I set the timeout to a minute, the test still reaches the expect in the same amount of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing the `done` function into your `let's do this` spec. Jasmine 2.0 runs the spec as synchronous or asynchronous based on the `length` property of the spec's function, so a no-args function will always run synchronous.

The code below is from Jasmine's GitHub (`/src/core/QueueRunner.js`).

```
for(iterativeIndex = recursiveIndex; iterativeIndex < length; iterativeIndex++) {
  var fn = fns[iterativeIndex];
  if (fn.length > 0) {
    return attemptAsync(fn);
  } else {
    attemptSync(fn);
  }
}
```

Also, don't forget to also call `done()` in the afterEach function, like so:

```
afterEach(function(done){
    expect(auth.user.Session).toBe(74790760);
    done();
});
```

Comment: Hi Eric, first of all thanks for your answer. So modifying it by passing the done function into my `let's do this` spec will end up in an error wich is quite confusing:

`Error - Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`

I did not use the default timeout intervall, instead I set the 2000 ms , wich should override the default timeout intervall. This even happens when I remove all code except for the `done()` call in the setTimeout call

Comment: It worked now thanks to your answer. Seems like I forgot to add `done();` at the end of the afterEach as well. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't look like there is anything in your `afterEach` that requires it to be async itself. By having the `it` be async, your `afterEach` won't be invoked until you call the `done` callback there. You should be fine to just remove the `done` argument from your `afterEach` entirely.